# PowerShell: Cannot spawn a new thread

Tags: c#, powershell

I am attempting to spawn a new thread in PowerShell's command line using:

```
$t = New-Object System.Threading.Thread ([System.Threading.ThreadStart]{ 
    Write-Host "Hello World" 
});

$t.Start();
```

What happens is that a dialog appears saying "Powershell has stopped working".

I want to use my own `Job` class, written in C#, with start, pause, continue and stop methods.  It uses a couple of `WaitHandles` to achieve this together with a new `Thead` instance.

I am aware of `Start-Job` etc, but would like to use real threads.

Any way?

**EDIT:**  There seems to be a way https://davewyatt.wordpress.com/2014/04/06/thread-synchronization-in-powershell/

Comment: Had quite afew crashes when playing with jobs recently. ...not sure if i had mandatory DEP/ASLR on at the time and never bothered looking at the logs

Comment: What is your PowerShell version you are testing on?

Comment: Following is the exception I get `CLR Version: v4.0.30319

[08:14:34] Exception: E0434F4D.System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException ("There is no Runspace available to run scripts in this thread
. You can provide one in the DefaultRunspace property of the System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace type. The script block you attempted to invoke was:
    Write-Host "Hello World"
")` but no idea how to resolve that.

Comment: [This thread](http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2009/10/09/PowerShell20AsynchronousCallbacksFromNET) might be of interest

Comment: Ok, so I am beginning to understand that every thread needs a runspace to execute code.

Comment: @TahirHassan Remember, PowerShell is not a native .NET/CLR language, you can't expect the runtime to behave as if you were compiling  C# or VB.NET. Don't think in terms of multiple threads, but rather [*multiple runspaces*](http://serverfault.com/questions/626711/how-do-i-run-my-powershell-scripts-in-parallel-without-using-jobs)

Comment: If you are writing your own job  class in C# then creating a runspace won't be much of an issue. Most examples of invoking PS from C# that I've seen include setting the runspace. The only exception would be a C# method that is called by Powershell and then invokes PS from within that method - in that case the method is already running on a PS thread. BTW, in creating your own job implementation you'll need to figure out how to marshal input and output from the PS script that creates and runs the job and the script that is the job. You might want to check out Adam Driscoll's blog on foreach PS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE** I have packaged the below into a module called `PSRunspacedDelegate`, which you can install using `Install-Package PSRunspacedDelegate`.  You can find [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/tahir-hassan/PSRunspacedDelegate).

---

[Adam Driscoll's PowerShell Parallel Foreach](http://csharpening.net/?p=441) explains that a thread running PowerShell code must have a `Runspace`.

In other words `[Runspace]::DefaultRunspace` cannot be null.

I ended up writing a `RunspacedDelegateModule.psm1` module, with a function `New-RunspacedDelegate` that does the work.

```
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\RunspacedDelegateFactory.cs"

Function New-RunspacedDelegate(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][System.Delegate]$Delegate, 
    [Runspace]$Runspace=[Runspace]::DefaultRunspace) {

    [PowerShell.RunspacedDelegateFactory]::NewRunspacedDelegate($Delegate, $Runspace)
}
```

RunspacedDelegateFactory.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace PowerShell
{
    public class RunspacedDelegateFactory
    {
        public static Delegate NewRunspacedDelegate(Delegate _delegate, Runspace runspace)
        {
            Action setRunspace = () => Runspace.DefaultRunspace = runspace;

            return ConcatActionToDelegate(setRunspace, _delegate);
        }

        private static Expression ExpressionInvoke(Delegate _delegate, params Expression[] arguments)
        {
            var invokeMethod = _delegate.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke");

            return Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(_delegate), invokeMethod, arguments);
        }

        public static Delegate ConcatActionToDelegate(Action a, Delegate d)
        {
            var parameters =
                d.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters()
                .Select(p => Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType, p.Name))
                .ToArray();

            Expression body = Expression.Block(ExpressionInvoke(a), ExpressionInvoke(d, parameters));

            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(d.GetType(), body, parameters);

            var compiled = lambda.Compile();

            return compiled;
        }
    }
}
```

What I noticed is that it would still crash if I used `Write-Host`, but `Out-File` seems to be ok.

Here is how to use it:

```
Import-Module RunspacedDelegateModule;
$writeHello = New-RunspacedDelegate ([System.Threading.ThreadStart]{ 
    "$([DateTime]::Now) hello world" | Out-File "C:\Temp\log.txt" -Append -Encoding utf8 
});
$t = New-Object System.Threading.Thread $writeHello;
$t.Start();
```